# Does a variable exist like UnityEvents but different

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

First, sorry if the title is confusing, but i don't know how to put it, let me explain, you know about unityevents right? well i want to know if there is something like that BUT instead of setting a script and then a function within that script, i would like it to set a script and then a variable in that script and check if it is a certain value.
So sorry if this is horribly written, but i have been pulling my hair out over this, if there is something that you would like to know please tell me.
Thank you

Comment: Can you provide a pseudocode example of what you're trying to achieve? Your description alone doesn't seem to fully illuminate the problem you're facing.

Comment: well basicly i would like something like this : https://imgur.com/a/4WXBV and then i could just do :                                                                            
 if (IfEvent == true) 
{
//do stuff 
}, hopefully you understand now @Serlite

Comment: Is the [event keyword](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/event) going to help achieve what you're after?  I don't entirely grasp what you're going for, but if you think that'll be helpful I'll write an example of it.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think this is possible the way you think (with a possibility to assign in the inspector).

However, what you are looking for are C# [Func](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534960%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

```
using UnityEngine;
using System;

public class MyMonoBehaviour: MonoBehaviour
{
    public Func<bool> MyTest ;

    private void Update()
    {
        if( MyTest != null && MyTest() )
        {
             Debug.Log("Success !");
        }
    }
}
```

---

```
using UnityEngine;

public class MyOtherMonoBehaviour: MonoBehaviour
{
    public MyMonoBehaviour MyMonoBehaviour ;

    private void Start()
    {
        MyMonoBehaviour.MyTest = AmIHandsome ;
    }

    private bool AmIHandsome()
    {
        return true ;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, i do need something like that, but if there isn't a way or something to be able to show in inspector (maybe custom inspector), then sadly i can't use it,But i will try it tomorow

Comment: Maybe you can create a custom inspector and play with Reflection in order to be able to use `Func` in the editor.

Comment: Good news, [uFAction](https://forum.unity.com/threads/free-ufaction-a-complete-set-of-serializable-and-inspectable-delegates.245248/) will let you serialize delegates (and Funcs) ;)